# how can I create an effect like this (two overlapping rectangles, and based on which one is tapped, switch color)

Tags: swift, swiftui

[image]

I am creating a customized tabbar in a "Edit Profile" view. User can switch between "edit" and "preview". I want it to look like two slightly overlapping rounded rectangles. The one selected has a more highlighted color.

I am having trouble drawing two overlapping rectangles.

Looking for ideas of how to make this.

This is my attempt of using ZStack and HStack. However I only see "Preview" drawn. I think there must be a smarter way of doing this.

```
ZStack {
        HStack(spacing: 0) {
            GeometryReader { geo in
                Text("Edit")
                    .font(.system(size: 20))
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                    .foregroundColor(.white.opacity(0.87))
                    .frame(width: geo.size.width/2 + 10)
                    .background(AppColor.backgroundColorL4)
                    .cornerRadius(5)
                
                Spacer() // So "Edit" is left aligned
            }
        }
            
        HStack(spacing: 0) {
            GeometryReader { geo in
                Spacer() // So "Preview" is right aligned
                Text("Preview")
                    .font(.system(size: 20))
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                    .foregroundColor(.white.opacity(0.87))
                    .frame(width: geo.size.width/2 + 10)
                    .background(AppColor.backgroundColorL4)
                    .cornerRadius(5)
            }
        }
            
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why you were only seeing one label with your original code is because there was no container to define the layout of the items inside each `GeometryReader`, so the `Spacer` and the `Text` were being shown on top of each other. If you swap the `HStack` and `GeometryReader` (in other words, use the `GeometryReader` as the container for the `HStack`, instead of vice versa) then both labels are shown.

Would I be right in thinking that the reason you want the two rectangles to be "slightly overlapping" is so that only the lighter gray shape is seen to have rounded corners? At the point where the two rectangles join, you don't want to see rounded corners on the non-selected side, right? In other words, there should be a continuous background behind the complete selector.

I would suggest using `.matchedGeometryEffect` to achieve the highlight effect. In addition:

- An `HStack` can be used as the top-level container.
- The continuous background can be achieved by applying a background effect to the `HStack`. This avoids the need for any overlapping.
- To split the space equally between the items, set `.frame(maxWidth: .infinity)` on each item. This avoids the need to use any `GeometryReader`.
- Set a `.contentShape` on each item, so that empty areas are also sensitive to tapping.

Like this:

```swift
@State private var selection = 0
@Namespace private var namespace

var body: some View {
    HStack(spacing: 0) {
        Text("Edit")
            .padding()
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            .contentShape(Rectangle())
            .matchedGeometryEffect(id: 0, in: namespace, isSource: selection == 0)
            .onTapGesture { selection = 0 }
        Text("Preview")
            .padding()
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            .contentShape(Rectangle())
            .matchedGeometryEffect(id: 1, in: namespace, isSource: selection == 1)
            .onTapGesture { selection = 1 }
    }
    .font(.system(size: 20))
    .fontWeight(.bold)
    .foregroundColor(.white.opacity(0.87))
    .background {

        // Marker that moves behind the selected item
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
            .fill(.gray) // AppColor.backgroundColorL4
            .matchedGeometryEffect(id: selection, in: namespace, isSource: false)
            .animation(.easeInOut, value: selection)
    }
    .background {

        // Background for the complete selector
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
            .fill(Color(white: 0.2))
    }
    .padding()
    .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
    .background(.black)
}
```

[image: Animation]

BTW, if you really want the selected side to be wider than half the width and to overlap the non-selected side by a little, negative padding can be used to achieve it. The order of modifiers is important. This seems to work:

```swift
Text("Edit")
    .padding()
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
    .matchedGeometryEffect(id: 0, in: namespace, isSource: selection == 0)
    .padding(.trailing, -10)
    .contentShape(Rectangle())
    .onTapGesture { selection = 0 }
```

For the second item, the negative padding needs to be `.leading`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a default SwiftUI component that supports this:

```swift
@State private var index = 0

Picker("Select number?", selection: $index) {
    Text("1").tag(0)
    Text("2").tag(1)
    Text("3").tag(2)
}
.pickerStyle(.segmented)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want a custom UI element for your purposes, here's some idea that works  as you described.

```swift
struct PlaygroundView: View {
  var body: some View {
    ZStack {
      Color.black
        .ignoresSafeArea()
      HStack(spacing: .zero) {
        Text("First")
          .foregroundStyle(Color.white)
          .padding()
          .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
          .onTapGesture {
            withAnimation { buttonIndex = 0 }
          }
        Text("Second")
          .foregroundStyle(Color.white)
          .padding()
          .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
          .onTapGesture {
            withAnimation { buttonIndex = 1 }
          }
        }
          .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 4.0))
          .background(Color.white.opacity(0.1))
          .background {
            HStack(spacing: -20.0) {
              if buttonIndex == 1 {
                Rectangle()
                  .opacity(.zero)
              }
              Rectangle()
                .fill(Color.white.opacity(0.1))
                .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 4.0))
              if buttonIndex == 0 {
                Rectangle()
                  .opacity(.zero)
              }
            }
          }
      }
    }
    @State private var buttonIndex = 0
}
```

The main idea is to put another `HStack` to the background of the "buttons" stack. Inside that background stack, there's a coloured rectangle that highlights the chosen option and two transparent rectangles. Depending on which option is picked, one transparent rectangle is excluded from the stack, making the coloured one move. Moving animation is ensured by `withAnimation`. The overlapping effect is achieved by a negative spacing of the background stack.

[image: Custom picker]

Comment: @Andrew_STOP_RU_WAR_IN_UA Thank you for your input, but  ask you to avoid descriptions like "too difficult" and "much better," they are subjective and don't bring any useful information.

Comment: "too difficult" is related to ".background()" modifier :) Try to add 1-2-3 new buttons and you will see```(as I have told you "too difficult to implement each new tab")```. And after - try to do the same action on solution of Benzy Neez and you will see that it's much more easy and took much less code and much more simple code logic