# Height resetting to 0 first when using a .matchedGeometryEffect() transition in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, geometryreader, matchedgeometryeffect

I'm struggling to understand why `.matchedGeometryEffect()` is behaving this way:

I'm trying to animate a tab's height to different heights, based on its content. To do so I'm using `.matchedGeometryEffect()` on the tab background as follow:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    // MARK: - Properties
    @State private var selectedTab: Tab = .payment
    @Namespace var namespace

    // MARK: - Body
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
            // Background color
            Color.gray6
                .ignoresSafeArea()
            
            // Tab
            switch selectedTab {
            case .dashboard:
                DashboardTabView(namespace: namespace)
                
            case .transactions:
                TransactionsTabView(namespace: namespace)
                
            case .payment:
                PaymentTabView(namespace: namespace)
                
            case .services:
                ServicesTabView(namespace: namespace)
                
            case .settings:
                SettingsTabView(namespace: namespace)
            }

        }
        .safeAreaInset(edge: .bottom, spacing: 0) {
            // Tab bar
            TabBar(selectedTab: $selectedTab)
        }
    }
}

struct DashboardTabView: View {

    // MARK: - Properties
    let namespace: Namespace.ID
    
    // MARK: - Body
    var body: some View {
        TabViewContainer(namespace: namespace) {
            Text("Dashboard Tab")
                .foregroundStyle(.black)
        }
    }
}

struct PaymentTabView: View {

    // MARK: - Properties
    let namespace: Namespace.ID

    // MARK: - Body
    var body: some View {
        TabViewContainer(namespace: namespace) {
            HStack(spacing: 16) {
                CTAButton(title: "Receive", icon: "arrow.down.square") { }

                CTAButton(title: "Pay", icon: "dollarsign.arrow.circlepath", color: Color(hex: "#F1D302")) { }
            }
            .frame(height: 52)
            .padding(.horizontal)
        }
    }
}

struct TabViewContainer<Content: View>: View {

    // MARK: - Init
    init(
        cornerRadii: RectangleCornerRadii = .init(topLeading: 21, bottomLeading: 0, bottomTrailing: 0, topTrailing: 21),
        namespace: Namespace.ID,
        @ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content
    ) {
        self.cornerRadii = cornerRadii
        self.namespace = namespace
        self.content = content
    }

    // MARK: - Properties
    let namespace: Namespace.ID
    @State private var childHeight: CGFloat = 0
    @ViewBuilder var content: () -> Content
    private let cornerRadii: RectangleCornerRadii

    // MARK: - Body
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
            // Background color
            Color.gray0
                .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "tab_background", in: namespace)
                .frame(height: childHeight)
                .clipShape(UnevenRoundedRectangle(cornerRadii: cornerRadii, style: .continuous))
            
            // Content
            content()
                .padding(.vertical)
                .overlay {
                    GeometryReader { proxy in
                        Color.clear
                            .task(id: proxy.size.height) {
                                childHeight = max(proxy.size.height, 0)
                            }
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

I can see the animation on the screen but it looks like instead of animating from the origin view to the destination view directly, it reset the height to 0 first, causing the animation to break.

Would anybody understand why it's behaving this way by any chance? Am I missing something in the implementation?

Here's what it looks like right now. I slowed down the animation on Xcode simulator so you can see it more clearly:

[Link to Xcode simulator demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFde1.gif)

I'm trying to display some tabs based on the `selectedTab` value in the `ContentView`. These tabs (`DashboardTabView`, `PaymentTabView`, etc) all leverage the same `TabViewContainer` that contains a `Color.gray0` view that uses `.matchedGeometryEffect(id: "tab_background", in: namespace)`.

My expectation is that these tab will transition height seamlessly from one tab to another, and in fact when I hard code the values for the height the animation is working propertly.

The problem arises when I use `GeometryReader` to retrieve the height of the `content()` child view. Then the animation breaks.

**UPDATE: 01/10**

I tried to pass a `selectedTab` environment key down the subviews to set `isSource` for the selected tab but it stopped animating all together.
Here's my new implementation:

```swift
struct SelectedTabEnvironmentKey: EnvironmentKey {
    static let defaultValue: Binding<Tab> = .constant(.payment)
}

extension EnvironmentValues {
    var selectedTab: Binding<Tab> {
        get { self[SelectedTabEnvironmentKey.self] }
        set { self[SelectedTabEnvironmentKey.self] = newValue }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {

    // MARK: - Properties
    @Namespace var namespace
    @State private var selectedTab: Tab = .payment

    // MARK: - Body
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
            // Tab
            switch selectedTab {
            case .dashboard:
                DashboardPage(namespace: namespace)
                
            case .transactions:
                TransactionsPage(namespace: namespace)
                
            case .payment:
                PaymentPage(namespace: namespace)
                
            case .services:
                ServicesPage(namespace: namespace)
                
            case .settings:
                SettingsPage(namespace: namespace)
            }

        }
        .environment(\.selectedTab, $selectedTab)
        .safeAreaInset(edge: .bottom, spacing: 0) {
            // Tab bar
            TabBar(selectedTab: $selectedTab)
        }
    }
}

struct DashboardPage: View {
    // MARK: - Properties
    let namespace: Namespace.ID

    // MARK: - Body
    var body: some View {
        Page(namespace: namespace) {
            // Content
            Text("Dashboard page")
                .foregroundStyle(.white)
                .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
            
        } tabView: {
            DashboardTabView(namespace: namespace)
        }
    }
}

struct Page<Content: View, TabView: TabViewProtocol>: View {

    // MARK: - Init
    init(
        namespace: Namespace.ID,
        @ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content,
        @ViewBuilder tabView: @escaping () -> TabView
    ) {
        self.namespace = namespace
        self.content = content
        self.tabView = tabView
    }

    // MARK: - Properties
    let namespace: Namespace.ID
    @ViewBuilder var content: () -> Content
    @ViewBuilder var tabView: () -> TabView
    @State private var tabViewHeight: CGFloat = 0

    // MARK: - Body
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
            // Background color
            Color.gray6
                .ignoresSafeArea()
            
            // Content
            VStack {
                content()
                
                Color.clear
                    .frame(height: tabViewHeight)
            }
            
            // Tab
            tabView()
                .overlay {
                    GeometryReader { proxy in
                        Color.clear
                            .task(id: proxy.size.height) {
                                guard proxy.size.height > 0 else { return }
                                tabViewHeight = max(proxy.size.height, 0)
                            }
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}

struct DashboardTabView: TabViewProtocol {

    // MARK: - Properties
    let namespace: Namespace.ID
    let transactions: [Transaction] = Transaction.section1
    @Environment(\.selectedTab) @Binding var selectedTab: Tab
    
    // MARK: - Body
    var body: some View {
        // Tab binding
        let isActive = Binding(
            get: { self.selectedTab == .dashboard },
            set: { _ in }
        )
        
        // View body
        return TabViewContainer(isActive: isActive, namespace: namespace) {
            VStack {
                // Header
                HStack {
                    Text("Transactions")
                        .font(.system(size: 15, weight: .medium))
                        .foregroundStyle(Color.gray6)
                    
                    Spacer()
                    
                    Text("See all")
                        .underline()
                        .foregroundStyle(Color.gray3)
                        .font(.system(size: 14, weight: .medium))
                }
                .padding(.vertical)
                
                // Transactions
                TransactionListSectionView(day: "Fri", date: "12", transactions: transactions)
            }
            .padding()
        }
    }
}

struct TabViewContainer<Content: View>: View {

    // MARK: - Init
    init(
        cornerRadii: RectangleCornerRadii = .init(topLeading: 21, bottomLeading: 0, bottomTrailing: 0, topTrailing: 21),
        isActive: Binding<Bool>,
        namespace: Namespace.ID,
        @ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content
    ) {
        self._isActive = isActive
        self.cornerRadii = cornerRadii
        self.namespace = namespace
        self.content = content
    }

    // MARK: - Properties
    let namespace: Namespace.ID
    @Binding var isActive: Bool
    @State private var childHeight: CGFloat = 0
    @ViewBuilder var content: () -> Content
    private let cornerRadii: RectangleCornerRadii

    // MARK: - Body
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
            // Background color
            Color.gray0
                .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "tab_background", in: namespace, isSource: isActive)
                .frame(height: childHeight)
                .clipShape(UnevenRoundedRectangle(cornerRadii: cornerRadii, style: .continuous))
            
            // Content
            content()
                .overlay {
                    GeometryReader { proxy in
                        Color.clear
                            .task(id: proxy.size.height) {
                                guard proxy.size.height > 0 else { return }
                                childHeight = max(proxy.size.height, 0)
                            }
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

In the example above, I'm just showing the `DashboardTabView` but all of the other tab views also have the same implementation and use the `TabViewContainer` component

Comment: Since hard coded heights are working normally, I suspect that `childHeight` is being set to 0 during the animation. If my assumptions are valid, a simple `guard proxy.size.height > 0 else {return}` should resolve your issue.

Comment: I just tried to add a guard statement, but it's still behaving the same.

Now, the weird thing is when I add a print statement to print the height in the task, the height is never resetted to 0 so I think the problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: I would be surprised if `.matchedGeometryEffect` is working at all here, because in the three cases where it is used, all the items have different ids and all have `isSource: true` (because this is the default). There should only ever be one item with `isSource: true`. The items having the same id but `isSource: false` will be matched to it. For an example of where `.matchedGeometryEffect` is working, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77750865/20386264).

Comment: Sorry I should've specify which `.matchGeometryEffect` id I was referring to. The problem is really with the ID `tab_background`. The other ones works fine (yes they match other IDs in the codebase).

My assumption was because this is a reusable view with the same ID (so the views are different but share the same ID) it would work. No?

Comment: @BenzyNeez I have added an environment key to keep track of the selected tab, which I use now to set the `isSource` to true depending on the tab.

```
struct SelectedTabEnvironmentKey: EnvironmentKey {
    static let defaultValue: Binding<Tab> = .constant(.payment)
}

extension EnvironmentValues {
    var selectedTab: Binding<Tab> {
        get { self[SelectedTabEnvironmentKey.self] }
        set { self[SelectedTabEnvironmentKey.self] = newValue }
    }
}
```

The animation stopped working all together. Still looking into it