# Animation on tap causing lag

Tags: swiftui

I have a custom segmented control view. In my main view, when one of the options is tapped, I load a different view:

```
@State private var selectedIndex = 0
let options: [SegmentedControlItem] = [
    SegmentedControlItem(name: "One"),
    SegmentedControlItem(name: "Two")
]

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        CustomSegmentedControl(
            selectedIndex: $selectedIndex,
            options: options
        )
        
        if (self.selectedIndex == 0) {
            ViewOne()
        } else {
            ViewTwo()
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my custom segmented control view:

```
import SwiftUI

struct SegmentedControlItem {
    var name: String? = nil
    var iconString: String? = nil
}

struct CustomSegmentedControl: View {
    @Binding var selectedIndex: Int
    let options: [SegmentedControlItem]
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .center) {
            GeometryReader { geo in
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .cornerRadius(16)
                    .padding(4)
                    .frame(width: geo.size.width / CGFloat(options.count))
                    .shadow(color: Color("Shadow Color").opacity(0.1), radius: 4, x: 0, y: 2)
                    .offset(x: geo.size.width / CGFloat(options.count) * CGFloat(selectedIndex), y: 0)
            }
            .frame(height: 48)
            
            HStack(spacing: 0) {
                ForEach((0..<options.count), id: \.self) { index in
                    HStack(spacing: 6) {
                        if let iconString = options[index].iconString {
                            Image(systemName: iconString)
                        }
                        if let name = options[index].name {
                            Text(name)
                        }
                    }
                    .font(.custom("Inter-Medium", size: 16))
                    .foregroundColor(selectedIndex == index ? Color("Primary Color") : Color.black.opacity(0.5))
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .frame(height: 48)
                    .contentShape(Rectangle())
                    .onTapGesture {
                        withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.150)) {
                            selectedIndex = index
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .background(
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 18)
                .fill(Color.wireframe)
        )
    }
}

#Preview {
    CustomSegmentedControl(
        selectedIndex: .constant(0),
        options: [
            SegmentedControlItem(name: "One"),
            SegmentedControlItem(name: "Two")
        ]
    )
}
```

However, I've noticed that when I tap one of the segmented control options, it lags when loading one of the two views. I've discovered that if I remove the `withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.150)) {` line, it no longer lags. But I would like to keep this animation.

So how can I keep this animation while updating the value of the `selectedIndex`?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need an animation in the opacity of the subviews, then use a separate state for tab indexes and the views:

```
struct CustomSegmentedControl: View {
    @Binding var selectedIndex: Int
    @State var selectedTabIndex: Int = 0
    let options: [SegmentedControlItem]

    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .center) {
            GeometryReader { geo in
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .cornerRadius(16)
                    .padding(4)
                    .frame(width: geo.size.width / CGFloat(options.count))
                    .shadow(color: Color.blue.opacity(0.1), radius: 4, x: 0, y: 2)
                    .offset(x: geo.size.width / CGFloat(options.count) * CGFloat(selectedTabIndex), y: 0)
            }
            .frame(height: 48)

            HStack(spacing: 0) {
                ForEach((0..<options.count), id: \.self) { index in
                    HStack(spacing: 6) {
                        if let iconString = options[index].iconString {
                            Image(systemName: iconString)
                        }
                        if let name = options[index].name {
                            Text(name)
                        }
                    }
                    .font(.system(size: 16))
                    .foregroundColor(selectedIndex == index ? Color.red : Color.black.opacity(0.5))
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .frame(height: 48)
                    .contentShape(Rectangle())
                    .onTapGesture {
                        selectedIndex = index
                        withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.150)) {
                            selectedTabIndex = index
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .background(
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 18)
                .fill(Color.pink)
        )
        .onAppear {
            selectedTabIndex = selectedIndex
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying this on a simulator, I didn't notice any significant lag, even when the animation is slowed down.

Anyway, I guess it may be related to the opacity transition that is used to switch between the views. You can avoid this by making the animation more specific to `CustomSegmentedControl`.

1. Add an `.animation` modifier to the `ZStack` of `CustomSegmentedControl`:

```swift
// CustomSegmentedControl

ZStack(alignment: .center) {
    // content as before
}
.background(
    // content as before
)
.animation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.150), value: selectedIndex) // <- ADDED
```

2. Then remove `withAnimation` from the `.onTapGesture`:

```swift
ForEach((0..<options.count), id: \.self) { index in
    // content as before
    .onTapGesture {
        selectedIndex = index // *not* withAnimation
    }
}
```

BTW, it might be easier to use `.matchedGeometryEffect` to move the `RoundedRectangle` behind the selection. See [how can I create an effect like this (two overlapping rectangles, and based on which one is tapped, switch color)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77750865/20386264) for an example of it being used in exactly this way.