# Is there a way to change the size of picker segments and their names?

Tags: ios, swiftui

I'm trying to get work with dynamic size in SwiftUI and I have this problem that the picker view is not actually applying the change.
The title of the picker will change it's size if I apply .dynamicTypeSize directly to the picker but it won't work for the segments and their names. (I'm using segmented picker style)

Is there any way for it to work?
What's the point of having dynamic ui if for example the user is using xxxLarge font size on its iPhone and then my App would apply that for all content but not for the picker? Looks strange.

I've tried to use dynamicTypeSize.

Here is a code sample from my view

```
.sheet(isPresented: $presentingModal) {
                    Spacer()
                    PickerView(title: eggSizes.title, options: eggSizes.options, selection: $eggTimerSettings.userSelections.size)
                        .padding(.horizontal)
                    PickerView(title: temperatures.title, options: temperatures.options, selection: $eggTimerSettings.userSelections.temperature)
                        .padding(.horizontal)
                    PickerView(title: donenessLevels.title, options: donenessLevels.options, selection: $eggTimerSettings.userSelections.doneness)
                        .padding(.horizontal)
                    Spacer()
                    Button(action: {
                        presentingModal.toggle()
                        navigate.toggle()
                    }, label: {
                        Text("Next")
                            .font(.system(.body, design: .rounded))
                            .fontWeight(.bold)
                            .foregroundStyle(.white)
                            .padding(.horizontal, 30)
                            .padding(.vertical, 15)
                            .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 30)
                                .foregroundStyle(.black))
                    })
                    .padding(.bottom, 10)
                    .presentationDetents([.fraction(0.5)])
                        .presentationDragIndicator(.visible)
                        .presentationCornerRadius(25)
                        .presentationBackground(.regularMaterial)
            }
                .navigationDestination(isPresented: $navigate) {
                    TimerView()
                        .environmentObject(eggTimerSettings)
                }
                
        }
        .dynamicTypeSize(...DynamicTypeSize.xxxLarge)
```

[image: Here is a screenshot of the picker]

Comment: Would you like to show us any of your code?

Comment: @matt I've added code and a screenshot.

Comment: Does any of the segmented pickers in the built-in apps respond to dynamic size changes. As far as I can remember, they don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't work to set a font size on a segmented picker, nor is it dynamic. However, it works to apply a `.scaleEffect`.

- Using a `ScaledMetric`, you can measure the font scaling and apply this to the `Picker`.
- In order to allow the layout to work normally, you might want to scale the frame of the picker too.

In the example below, the `Picker` has a `Divider` above and below it, to show how the height is being scaled too:

```swift
private enum Choice: CaseIterable, Identifiable {
    case first
    case second
    case third

    var id: Choice { self }
    var name: String { "\(self)".capitalized }
}

struct ContentView: View {

    @ScaledMetric(relativeTo: .footnote) private var fontRefSize = 100.0
    @State private var selection = Choice.first

    private var fontScalingFactor: CGFloat {
        max(1, (fontRefSize / 100))
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            Text("Body font")
            Divider()

            Picker("Choice", selection: $selection) {
                ForEach(Choice.allCases) { choice in
                    Text(choice.name)
                }
            }
            .pickerStyle(.segmented)
            .fixedSize()
            .scaleEffect(fontScalingFactor)
            .frame(minHeight: 30 * fontScalingFactor)

            Divider()
        }
        .padding(.top, 50)
        .frame(maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .top)
    }
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

One disadvantage of this approach is that all aspects of the picker get scaled. So this includes the thickness of the border, for example.

An alternative approach is to build your own custom segmented picker, which is not very difficult.

- By building it yourself, you have full control of styling. You can also choose to allow the choices to wrap to multi-line, if you wish.
- For moving a shape behind the selection, `.matchedGeometryEffect` can be used. This is illustrated in the answer to [how can I create an effect like this (two overlapping rectangles, and based on which one is tapped, switch color)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77750865/20386264).